# Hide Empty Filtered ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am looking to hide a category if it it empty. My current solution is not working:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="items in shop | unique : 'cat' | orderBy: 'cat'">
       <h2>{{items.cat}}</h2>
       <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="items in shop | filter:{cat: items.cat} | filter:query"
                 <h3>{{items.name}}</h3>
            </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My Filter "unique" looks like so:

```
app.filter('unique', function() {
   return function(collection, keyname) {
      var output = [],
          keys = [];

      angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
          var key = item[keyname];
          if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
              keys.push(key);
              output.push(item);
          }
      });

      return output;
   };
});
```

JSON:

```
{
  "businesses" : {
    "-KQ1ggyrnYGYL1084Htz" : {
      "name" : "business name",
      "cat" : "food",
    },
}
```

I assume that I could do something with ng-if and/or ng-hide/show but none of the combos I have done work.

Comment: Can you show your JSON?

Comment: Yes, I updated with JSON, I apologize for not having it prior. And I think your answer would work but I'm looking at doing it for the top level ng-repeat. It's a nested ng-repeat. That solution works for child. But I'm looking at hiding the parent "cat" label if empty. Thanks

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: How did you get on with it?

Comment: The answer was actually simpler than I expected. I just had to filter the parent repeat by the same query. `data-ng-repeat="items in shop | unique : 'cat' | orderBy: 'cat' | filter:query"` Thanks for all the help. I think my question was worded poorly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ngIf`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive or the [`ngShow`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)/[`ngHide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) directives.

How you use them depends on your JSON.

Heres an example of the `ngIf` with some basic data:

```js
(function() {

  angular.module('MyApp', []);

})();

(function() {

  angular.module('MyApp').controller('MyController', MyController);

  MyController.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MyController($scope) {

    $scope.shop = [{
      name: "test 1",
      cat: "cat 1"
    }, {
      name: "test 2",
      cat: "cat 3"
    }, {
      name: "test 3",
      cat: ""
    }, {
      name: "test 4",
      cat: "cat 4"
    }];

  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div data-ng-app="MyApp">

  <div data-ng-controller="MyController">

    <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="items in shop | orderBy: 'cat'" ng-if="items.cat">
        <h2>{{items.cat}}</h2>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="items in shop | filter:{cat: items.cat}">
            <h3>{{items.name}}</h3>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>

</div>
```